I have deleted the default taxonomy term view and I have trouble restoring it from a backup, how to proceed?
10.2.6 core with no PHP customization.
I have deleted the default taxonomy term view based on the thought that I might have changed it in the past and don't recall if, when and how.
Now I am stuck with empty taxonomy term pages (all taxonomy term pages exist but don't show any associated nodes).
Pasting all content of web/core/modules/taxonomy/config/optional/views.view.taxonomy_term.yml into:
/admin/config/development/configuration/single/import brings this error:

The configuration cannot be imported because it failed validation for the following reasons:
Configuration core.entity_view_display.node.dp_byt.default depends on the field.field.node.dp_byt.layout_builder__layout configuration that will not exist after import.

I don't know what it means.
The error might be related to the fact that the main language of my website is not English (the original taxonomy term view page was translated).
English is enabled as well, but as a secondary language.
I have deleted the default taxonomy term view and I have trouble restoring it from a backup, how to proceed? Perhaps the better question should be how to create a minimal taxonomy term View?

This is not an answer to your question, but if you always export config (drush cex) and commit the exported files to git before making changes, you can easily undo any future changes to avoid this kind of problem.

It appears that the layout_builder__layout field has been deleted from your dp_byt content type, which is causing the issue. You can try re-creating this field and then attempt the import again. Alternatively, if you need a default taxonomy term view, you can copy the views.view.taxonomy_term.yml file from a new Drupal setup and import it. This will provide you with a minimal view that you can then adjust according to your requirements.
